# IE8 - Table Opacity Lost in Quirks mode When F11 is pressed

Tags: css, iframe, html-table, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I have a jsp webpage wherein I need to Dim a table inside an iframe, I successfully dim the table but when F11 is pressed the table opacity is lost.

I need a workaround on this because rewriting the whole page will take time. I have hundreds of jsp pages that has iframes and only in quirks mode.

Here is the equivalent html that reproduces the problem

**MAIN PAGE**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<table width=100% height=100%>
<tr>
 <td>
  <iframe src="\test2.html" width=100% height=100%>

  </iframe>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**END OF MAIN PAGE**

**CALLED PAGE**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table width=100% height=100%>
<tr>
 <td>
    <table width=100% style="background-color :gray; filter:alpha(opacity=30);">
        <tr>
            <td height="500" width ="500">
                <p>TESTING</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**END CALLED PAGE PAGE**

Replies will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe, don't use quirks mode?

Comment: Yup! that's what I did eventually for this specific page with opacity. I managed to workaround the opacity bug. But now I have problems on the sizing of iframe heights.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve the issue, but you can try to force the rendering mode so that you maintain consistency across views.

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201103/x-ua-compatible_and_html5/

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Could be an issue with the filter opacity in the browser. What browser and version are you working with?

Try this for IE8. From http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

```
.opaque {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // first!
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);                  // second!
}
```

Comment: I tried using IE=EmulateIE7 and others but it just messes the display of the page.

Haven't tried IE=edge, I'll get back to you if this works. Thanks!